# Alamofire publishDecodable does not send request to server but responseDecodable does

Tags: swift, alamofire, combine

This piece of code does not result in a logged request on my server or a printed result.

```
AF.request(endpoint, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: nil)
            .validate().publishDecodable(type: Token.self, decoder: decoder).value().print()
```

This, however, does:

```
AF.request(endpoint, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: nil)
            .validate().responseDecodable(of: Token.self, decoder: decoder){
                print($0)
            }
```

How should the former be modified to produce the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't subscribed to the published stream so no request is made. Alamofire's Publishers are lazy, which means they only make a request once they're received a subscription to the result. You need to use a `sink` or otherwise subscribe to the output for the request to be made. `.print()` in Combine is an operator which provides insight into the stream, it doesn't subscribe to the stream. For the equivalent to your other example, use `.sink { print($0) }` and store the token somewhere.